# Oracle SQL My input should be the format mask in to_char(:n,'fm000')

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

If my string has more length than 4 digits then my output is displayed as #######

For that the query is:

```
select to_char(:n,'fm0000') from dual;
```

It should take the number of zeros based on the input bind variables length after **fm**.

INPUT : 123
OUTPUT: 0123

INPUT : 123456789
OUTPUT: 0123456789

Zero should come before the number of input.

---

Any Suggestions!!

Comment: What's the point of the format mask? You want leading zeros if the value is less than four digits, but not if it's longer that that?

Comment: Basically Why I require it is
If I give input 123 my output should be 0123
If INPUT : 123456789 OUTPUT: 0123456789
Zero should be before that

Comment: You always want a single zero appended to the front of the value? What if it is just 1 - should it be displayed as 01 or 0001?

Comment: it should be displayed as 01 only.

Comment: @AkshayBhan - do you realize that is quite different from what you asked originally? What you are asking now is much easier, why don't you just use `'0' || to_char(:n)`? Concatenate a single zero to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** - the OP changed the requirement completely.

The solution to the edited problem is trivial:

```
... '0' || to_char(:n)
```

**End of edit** - Original answer (to the question as originally posted) below.

It seems what you are trying to do is best achieved like this. Never mind the `with` clause, that is only for testing. Adapt as needed, and use enough nines in the format model to cover your longest inputs.

```
with
     test_data ( n ) as (
       select 3     from dual union all
       select 19923 from dual
     )
select n, to_char(n, 'fm99990000') as n_str
from   test_data
;

     N N_STR
------ --------
     3 0003
 19923 19923

2 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm)

> If you omit fmt, then n is converted to a VARCHAR2 value exactly long
>   enough to hold its significant digits

so perhaps all you need is `to_char(:n)`

Comment: Rather use TO_NUMBER(:n)

Comment: @GauravSoni - why - the OP is formatting a number as a string for display, not converting a string to a number?

Comment: @AlexPoole: If it is for display then it makes sense to me

Comment: @GauravSoni - Alex is probably right - it seems the OP wants to show 3 as '0003', 300 as '0300' but 13391 as '13391'.

Comment: INPUT : 123 OUTPUT: 0123

INPUT : 123456789 OUTPUT: 0123456789

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated requirement, you can do this with a slight modification of @mathguy's original format mask manipulation; or with default conversion to a string and left-padding, or even more simly just prepending a single zero:

```
with t (n) as (
  select 1 from dual
  union all select 123 from dual
  union all select 123456789 from dual
)
select n,
  to_char(n, 'fm' || rpad('0', length(n) + 1, '0')) as n_str_1,
  lpad(to_char(n), length(n) + 1, '0') as n_str_2,
  '0' || to_char(n) as n_str_3
from t;

         N N_STR_1    N_STR_2    N_STR_3   
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 01         01         01        
       123 0123       0123       0123      
 123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

If the field you are checking is a string:

```
case when substring(field, 1, 1)!=0 then '0'||field else field end
```

If it's a number you can always add a 0 as proposed by others:

```
'0'||to_char(field)
```